# Inner Join with Where condition on both tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm building a calendar and I need some help with my SQL queries.

I have the following tables:

`event`
`attendees`

`attendees` is a `join table` that joins Facebook User ID's to event ID's with a many-many relationship.

I need to run a query that get's all the events where the attendee's `UID` matches the user's and where the event's `month` and `year` field match the month and year input by the user.

I'm not sure how to do it. I know I need an inner join, but beyond that I have no idea what I'm doing.

**Edit**

So as an example, if I have the following data

`Attendee` `id=1` `uid=065786593` `isCancelled=0` `eventID=3`

`Attendee` `id=2` `uid=065786593` `isCancelled=0` `eventID=4`

`Attendee` `id=3` `uid=065786593` `isCancelled=0` `eventID=5`

`Attendee` `id=4` `uid=056836251` `isCancelled=0` `eventID=6`

`event` `id=3` `title=Meeting with Manager` `day=06` `month=12` `year=2017`

`event` `id=4` `title=Job Interview` `day=15` `month=12` `year=2017`

`event` `id=5` `title=Celebrate new year` `day=01` `month=01` `year=2018`

`event` `id=6` `title=christmas night out` `day=22` `month=12` `year=2017`

when I run the query for this month's calendar (12/2017) as user `065786593` I would expect to get events 3 and 4 in the result

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you have a many to many relationship, then you need 3 tables, not just two.

Comment: I updated the question with some example data and the expected output @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Shadow I am linked into facebook. I'm not storing any user information (which would be the 3rd table you're talking about) except the UID (which is used to get facebook profile data)... so it's actually many users to many events and `attendees` is the join table

Comment: I'll update the question to reflect that (not that I've thought about it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select event.id, event.title, event.day
from attendee
join event on attendee.eventID=event.id
where attendee.uid=? and event.year=? and event.month=?
```

Comment: yes! this worked! except I had a few more fields I needed so I used `event.*`.... thanks :)